# How to get a python SocketServer to received until string is terminated with NUL

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, socketserver, nul

In Python, how would I go about writing a TCP SocketServer receiving a string until a NUL character (`\0`) is found? After the string is received fully, I need the socket to continue to be able to receive new strings.

Comment: @Celada 
I don't have any code besides a basic SocketServer (self.request.recv(1024)), I honestly have no idea how to do this, therefore, I need help

Answer (score 0):

On reading the documentation you want to use "the [alternative request handler class](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socketserver.html) that makes use of streams (file-like objects that simplify communication by providing the standard file interface)":

```
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
```

Once you have a file like interface you can extract the bytes till you get the '\0' NUL character. You'll block on the read() requests.